# Página pisca ao dar F5

Tags: html

Não sei se minha dúvida é algo comum ou não.

Estou criando um site, ele está totalmente otimizado (Imagens super leves, Códigos, Scripts e etc.), no entanto, sempre que atualizo a página, ele meio que pisca uma tela branca rapidamente e abre a página. Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Você quer dizer que há uma tela branca mais demorada ou com comportamento diferente de outras páginas da Web?

Comment: Ela pisca em branco, bem rapidamente. Eu sei que as informações estão vindo do servidor. Mas já vi sites que não apresentam isso. Queria saber se existe uma forma de conter...

Comment: Pode ser um caso de _Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC)_. Tens o site online? senão podes colocar um exepmlo online e o código aqui? O site está dependente de JavaCript no inicio?

Answer (score 0):

Evitar completamente, acredito que não tenha uma solução definitiva, mas existem algumas práticas que vão ajudar você a mitigar esse problema, algumas feitas no lado do cliente e outras no servidor mesmo.

**Html**

- Folhas de estilho deve ser declaradas no início do arquivo.
- Scripts devem ser declarados no final do arquivo.
- Adicione uma cor de fundo através do atributo e estilo na tag `<html>` e `<body>`
  `<body bgcolor="#ccc" style="background-color:#ccc;">`
- Evite realizar requisições `POST` quando um `GET` pode ser usado

**Servidor**

- Configurar e habilitar o Cache.
- Compressão para transferência de arquivos
  estáticos (GZIP)
- Distribuir os conteúdos que podem ser baixados paralelamente em diferentes hosts (CDN)